# How to set HTTP cache-control from .net web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a legacy C# web service (class inheriting `System.Web.Services.WebService`) with a series of WebMethods like so:

```
[WebMethod, SoapHeader("header", Direction=SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
[SoapDocumentMethod("http://www.myservices.com/Services/1.1#getMediaMetadata")]
public MediaMetadata getMediaMetadata(string id)
{
    return new MediaService().GetMetadata( id );
}
```

I am attempting to set the cache-control header on the response via `HttpResponse.Cache.SetMaxAge`.  Executing the service yields a default header:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
```

I replaced the standard `Cache.SetMaxAge` with a hardcoded header:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader( "Cache-Control", "private, max-age=" + (int)ttl.TotalSeconds );
```

Yet still the web server responds with the default Cache-Control.  I suspect ASP.NET web services are mucking this up after execution of the web method.  The suggestion below to use the CacheDuration attribute of WebMethod is not applicable in my scenario.

Any advice?

Comment: I now suspect that the problem lies in the fact that clients are POSTing to the web method, and the HTTP spec says that Cache-Control is irrelevant on POST.  Apparently asp.net is ignoring the SetMaxAge invocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration=60), SoapHeader("header", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)] 
SoapDocumentMethod("http://www.myservices.com/Services/1.1#getMediaMetadata")]   
public MediaMetadata getMediaMetadata(string id)   
{   
    return new MediaService().GetMetadata( id );   
}
```

Add this attribute to your Should do the trick.

If you specifically wanted to access the context then

```
Context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

You will be safe to access the context unless it's null. A simple check will solve this for you

Comment: Thanks, I was unable to use the CacheDuration attrib because the values will change based on the request.  I know that some types of webmethods (one-way) may not have a valid HttpContext.  The question was whether there is some "official" way to reference it from a webmethod.

Comment: im not 100% sure but isn't CacheDuration just for server caching? if i set it i still get "Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Expires: -1" and Cache.SetMaxAge has no effect...